# XSL: Replace two sibling elements with one

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to replace this XML:

```
<name type="personal" authority="local">
  <namePart>Gertrude</namePart>
  <namePart type="termsOfAddress">Aunt</namePart>
  <role>
     <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Correspondent</roleTerm>
     <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">crp</roleTerm>
  </role>
</name>
```

with this XML:

```
<name type="personal" authority="local">
  <namePart>Aunt Gertrude</namePart>
  <role>
     <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Correspondent</roleTerm>
     <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">crp</roleTerm>
  </role>
</name>
```

while still retaining the rest of the document. I've tried two methods: one that works, but seems stupid, and one that doesn't work, and seems just as stupid.

First Method

```
<xsl:template match="* | processing-instruction() | comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//name/namePart[matches(., 'Gertrude')
                    and following-sibling::namePart[@type='termsOfAddress'
                        and matches(., 'Aunt')]]">
    <namePart>Aunt Gertrude</namePart>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//name/namePart[@type='termsOfAddress'
                       and matches(., 'Aunt')
                       and preceding-sibling::namePart[matches(., 'Gertrude')]]"/>
```

Seoncd Method

```
    <xsl:template match="* | processing-instruction() | comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//name[descendant::namePart[matches(., 'Gertrude')]
                         and descendant::namePart[@type='termsOfAddress' 
                         and matches(., 'Aunt')]]/namePart">
    <namePart>Aunt Gertrude</namePart>
</xsl:template>
```

So, like I said, the first one works, but having two separate templates to handle the two elements seemed somewhat redundant. So I tried the second method which gave me this:

```
<name type="personal" authority="local">
   <namePart>Aunt Gertrude</namePart>
   <namePart>Aunt Gertrude</namePart>
   <role>
      <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Correspondent</roleTerm>
      <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">crp</roleTerm>
   </role>
</name>
```

Which is not what I want.

Is there any way to select both namePart elements and replace it with one?

Comment: There are many methods, however you don't explain in what order (the rule for ordering) should the values be concatenated into a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

    <namePart>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="namePart">
        <xsl:sort select="count(@*)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </namePart>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::namePart)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="namePart">
   <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<name type="personal" authority="local">
  <namePart>Gertrude</namePart>
  <namePart type="termsOfAddress">Aunt</namePart>
  <role>
     <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Correspondent</roleTerm>
     <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">crp</roleTerm>
  </role>
</name>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<name type="personal" authority="local">
   <namePart>Gertrude Aunt</namePart>
   <role>
      <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Correspondent</roleTerm>
      <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">crp</roleTerm>
   </role>
</name>
```

Comment: Thanks to Alejandro, who alerted me about a misconception in the first version of this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there are other `<namePart>` elements that I DO want to copy in the document that would match the `<xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">` requirement. The document I'm working with is actually quite a bit larger than I gave here and includes multiple `//name/namePart` trees.

In this case, my first solution may be best because it does take the specific sibling I don't want into consideration, though I could possibly come up with some code in the `* | processing-instruction() | comment()` template to account for the `<nameParts>` I don't want. 

Thanks!

Comment: @user1655528, If you want a useful answer to the problem, then you need to include sufficient data. Even in this cut example it isn't specified in what order should the string be concatenated. I strongly recommend that you think it over and ask a new question that contains sufficient and representative XML document and the exact wanted result, and also provide complete, unambiguous requirements -- possibly as a list of different use-cases, so that people wouldn't have to guess and provide answers that due to their guesses are not the ones that you want.

Comment: I apologize, your answer was actually quite useful as it helped me understand more of the requirements of my problem, why the first example functions, but the second one doesn't, and what I need to consider when composing the XSL. I was attempting to make my question as applicable as possible, but ended up just being ambiguous. Indeed, because of my ignorance, I actually asked I question that I believe I already answered: how to select two nodes. My first example does actually select two nodes, it's just that the first template ALSO selects the node I don't want. Again, thank you, and sorry.